# What is the word I'm looking for? Synonymous to arrogant or ostensibly knowledgable

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't quite remember what this words is:

The definition goes somewhere along the lines of "Making remarks correcting trivial mistakes in another's statement as to appear knowledgeable".

I specifically remember reading a definition like that on thefreedictionary.com.

Comment: Are you looking for *pedantic* (which doesn't quite have the "so as to appear knowledgeable" part) but feels like maybe it's the word you had in mind.

Comment: Stackexchange disconnected me from the previous account as I registered a password to it, so I can't accept the answer or put this as a comment. Nonetheless, Centaurus has the right answer; the word I'm looking for is "pedantic". (Side note: And as Jim points out in the comments, it doesn't quite have the mentioned wording I said would be on thefreedictionary. Rather, I must have remembered the formulation on the [Wikipedia article of "Pedant"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedant).)

Comment: Also "pontificating": pontificate/pontify is to speak or behave in a pompous or dogmatic manner.

Comment: Can you give an example sentence? (It is not yet clear what you want)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for ***a pseudo-intellectual?***

> - a person who wants to be thought of as having a lot of intelligence and knowledge but who is not really intelligent or knowledgeable [MW](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/pseudo%E2%80%93intellectual)

**a show-off?**

> - a person who acts pretentiously or who publicly parades themselves, their possessions, or their accomplishments. [Google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=pseudo-intelectual+definition&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gfe_rd=cr&ei=cHb3VeIfw4HxB62OpKAM&gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=show-off+definition)

**or a pedant?**

> - a person who is excessively concerned with minor details and rules or with displaying academic learning.  one who makes a show of knowledge. [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedant)

Answer (score 0):

Nit-picking?  The [Free Dictionary definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nitpicking) is close to your description in text, though I wouldn't call "nit-picking" synonymous with being arrogant.